# Creating interactive scheme in LaTex

Tags: diagrams, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing, hyperlink

We want to create a scheme and it should be:

- horizontal
- multi-level
- easily editable
- it must be the connecting line (but no cross-links)
- grouping of nodes (the block may contain more than 10 lines )
- optimally to fill the page
- contains hyperlinks

**Our attempts:**

*Drawing in LaTex* - This case is very difficult to use, especially if diagram will change ( for example add a block in middle)

*Create a diagram* - All diagrams  that we've tried, to be not compact

*Create a list (enumeration)* -  There is no possibility to see scheme as a whole, no connecting lines, level of list is limited.

**Questions:**

1. What can you advise solution to our problem?
2. What solution is best to use?
3. There are other ways to solve problem?

**Example of a schema:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
    \documentclass{report} %%---------Drawing in LaTex------------
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 
    \usepackage{graphics}

    \begin{document}

    \section{section}
    \label{secc}
    \newpage
    \begin{picture}(100,100)
    \put(0,0){\oval(100,100)}
    \put(-30,0){
        \begin{tabular}{l}
        \hyperref[secc]{ref1}\\
        \hyperref[secc]{ref2}\\
        \hyperref[secc]{ref3}\\
        \hyperref[secc]{ref4}\\
        \hyperref[secc]{ref5}\\
        \hyperref[secc]{ref6}\\
        \end{tabular}
        }
    \put(50,0){\oval(50,50)[rt]}
    \put(100,0){\oval(50,50)[lb]}
    \put(150,-50){\oval(100,200)}

    \put(120,0){
        \begin{tabular}{l}
        \hyperref[secc]{ref12}\\
        \hyperref[secc]{ref22}\\
        \hyperref[secc]{ref32}\\
        \hyperref[secc]{ref42}\\
        \hyperref[secc]{ref52}\\
        \hyperref[secc]{ref62}\\
        \end{tabular}
        }

    \put(50,0){\oval(25,25)[rt]}
    \put(62.5,0){\line(0,-1){100}}
    \put(50,-100){\oval(25,25)[rb]}

    \put(0,-125){\oval(100,100)}
    \end{picture}

    \end{document}

\documentclass[tikz, margin=10mm]{standalone} %%---------Create a diagram-------
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \section{Docktrial}
    \label{sec:docktrial}
    \section{AP Modes}
    \label{sec:apmodes}
    \section{Track Mode}
    \label{sec:trackmode}
    \clearpage

   \begin{forest}
    for tree={% style of tree nodes
      draw, semithick, rounded corners, drop shadow,
        top color = blue!5,
     bottom color = blue!5,
       text width = 35mm, text badly centered,
              % style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
             edge = {draw, semithick},
           anchor = east,
             grow = east,
    forked edge,            % for forked edge
            s sep = 1mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 4mm,    % level distance
         fork sep = 2mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
               }
[{\hyperref[sec:docktrial]{\textbf{Docktrial}}}
    [\textbf{Configuration}]
    [Alarm timeout]
    [Mode select]
    [\textbf{Ext devices}
        [ROT Tiller]
        [\textbf{GPS position}
            [V filter]
            [X corr]
            [Pos Source]
            [Reserved3]
            [Reserved2]
            [Reserved1]
            [S filter]
            [M filter]
            [Z]
            [Y]
            [X]
        ]
        [\textbf{Speed joystick}
            [Speed Rudder Limit]
            [Parking]
            [JSync Type]
            [Set HDG]
            [High Gain Type]
            [High Gain]
            [V min Current]
            [VX High]
            [VY max]
            [VX aft max]
            [VX fore max]
        ]
        [Joystick polling]
        [Tillers ID Assign]
        [Dodge Tiller]
        [Steering Wheel]
    ]
    [Manual tuning]
    [Station]
    [{\hyperref[sec:apmodes]{\textbf{AP Modes}}}
        [Dodge mode]
        [River mode]
        [CTS mode]
        [Wind Vane mode]
        [{\hyperref[sec:trackmode]{Track mode}}]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}    
\end{document}

\documentclass{report} %%---------Create a list (enumeration)-------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Docktrial 
        \begin{itemize}
            \item AP Modes
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Track mode 
                    \item Wind Vane mode
                    \item CTS mode
                    \item River mode
                    \item Dodge mode
                \end{itemize}
            \item Station
            \item Manual tuning
            \item Ext devices 
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Steering Weel  
                    \item Dodge Tiller
                    \item Tillers ID Assign
                    \item Joystick polling
                    \item Speed joystick
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item VX force max  
                            \item VX aft max
                            \item VY max
                            \item Vx High 
                            \item V min Current 
                            \item High Gain 
                            \item High gain type 
                            \item Set HDG
                            \item JSync Type 
                            \item Parking 
                            \item Speed Rudder Limit
                        \end{itemize}
                    \item GPS position 
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item X   
                            \item Y
                            \item Z
                            \item M filter 
                            \item S filter 
                            \item Reserved 1 
                            \item Reserved 2 
                            \item Reserved 3 
                            \item Pos source  
                            \item X corr
                            \item V filter
                        \end{itemize}
                    \item ROT tiller
                \end{itemize}
            \item Mode select
            \item Alarm timeout
            \item Configuration 
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item Device mode 
                    \item JP Installation
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item JP config
                            \item JP Ext config
                            \item Reduce config
                            \item JP station 
                            \item Monitor type 
                            \item Low power
                            \item WJ booster
                            \item JFail Exit 
                            \item Ahead Type  
                            \item Smoothing
                            \item Limitation
                            \item Allocation
                            \item Password 
                        \end{itemize}
                    \item JP modes
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item Anchor Watch
                            \item Hold Position
                            \item Strong Current
                            \item Joystick Ferry 
                            \item Joystick auto 
                            \item Joystick speed  
                            \item Joystick Low Track  
                            \item Joystick High Track 
                            \item Joystick Coord 
                            \item Password
                            \item Secure Code
                        \end{itemize}
                    \item Low Speed HC
                    \item 3 rudders 
                    \item Password
                \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[edges]{forest}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \tikzset{parent/.style={align=center,text width=0.4cm,rounded corners=3pt}, 
        child/.style={align=center,text width=5cm,rounded corners=3pt}
    }
    \colorlet{col1}{white}
    \colorlet{col2}{cyan!5}
    \colorlet{col3}{cyan!15}
    \colorlet{col4}{cyan!30}  

    \begin{document}
    \section{Docktrial}
    \label{sec:docktrial}
    \section{AP Modes}
    \label{sec:apmodes}

    \clearpage

        \begin{center}
            \resizebox*{.94\linewidth}{!}{%
                \begin{forest}
                    forked edges,
                    for tree={
                        grow'=east,
                        draw,
                        l sep = 12mm,
                        fork sep = 6mm,
                        rounded corners,
                        text width=4.7cm,
                        node options={align=center},
                    }     
           [,fill=col1, draw=white, parent, s sep=1cm  
                [{\hyperref[sec:docktrial]{\textbf{Docktrial}}}, for tree={child, fill=col4, draw=col4, edge=white}
                    [{\hyperref[sec:apmodes]{\textbf{AP Modes}}}, for tree={child, fill=col4, draw=col4, edge=black}, s sep=0mm
                            [Track mode, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                            [Wind Vine mode, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                            [CTS mode, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                            [River mode, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                            [Dodge mode, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                    ]
                    [Station, for tree={child, fill=col2, draw=col4, edge=black}]
                    [Manual tuning, for tree={child, fill=col1, draw=col4, edge=black}]
                    [\textbf{Ext devices}, for tree={child, fill=col4, draw=col4, edge=black}, s sep=0mm
                            [Steering Wheel, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                            [Dodge Tiller, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                            [Tillers ID Assign, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                            [Joystick polling, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                            [\textbf{Speed joystick}, calign=last, for tree={child, fill=col2}, s sep=0mm
                                    [Vx fore max, for tree={child, fill=col2}] 
                                    [Vx aft max, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Vy max, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                                    [Vx High, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [V min Current, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                                    [High Gain, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [High Gain Type, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                                    [Set HDG, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [JSync Type, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                                    [Parking, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Speed Rudder Limit, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                            ]
                            [\textbf{GPS position}, calign=first, for tree={child, fill=col3, edge=black},  s sep=0mm
                                    [X, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Y, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                                    [Z, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [M filter, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                                    [S filter, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Reserved1, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                                    [Reserved2, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Reserved3, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                                    [Pos Source, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [X corr, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                                    [V filter, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                            ] 
                            [ROT Tiller, for tree={child, fill=col1}, edge=black]
                    ]
                    [Mode select, for tree={child, fill=col2}, edge=black]
                    [Alarm timeout, for tree={child, fill=col1}, edge=black]
                    [\textbf{Configuration}, for tree={child, fill=col4, edge=black}, s sep=2mm
                            [Device mode, for tree={child, fill=col1}, edge=black]
                            [\textbf{JP Installation}, calign=last, for tree={child, fill=col2, edge=black},  s sep=0mm
                                    [JP config, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                                    [JP Ext config, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Reduce config, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                                    [JP station, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Monitor type, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                                    [Low power, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [WJ booster, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                                    [JFail Exit, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Ahead Type, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                                    [Smoothing, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Limitation, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                                    [Allocation, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Password, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                            ]
                            [\textbf{JP modes}, calign=first, for tree={child, fill=col3},  s sep=0mm
                                    [Anchor Watch, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Hold Position, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                                    [Strong Current, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Joystick Ferry, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                                    [Joystick Auto, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Joystick Speed, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                                    [Joystick Low Track, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Joystick High Track, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                                    [Joystick Horsing, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Joystick Weathervan, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                                    [Joystick Coord, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                                    [Password, for tree={child, fill=col3}]
                                    [Secure Code, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                            ]
                            [Low Speed HC, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                            [3 rudders, for tree={child, fill=col2}]
                            [Password, for tree={child, fill=col1}]
                    ]
                    ]
           ]
                \end{forest}}
            \end{center}
\end{document}
```